# "Invalid Magic Number" after updating kernel post-install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

After selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, I immediately get an error as the title describes. The only line before this is about loading the ramdisk (I can take a picture and post it to Imgur or similar if that helps).

I can get in using a Live CD - `fsck`ing the bootable partition doesn't reveal any errors. I've tried `chroot`ing in and running `grub-install` but that immediately complains about not being able to resolve `/cow` or something similar ..

Interestingly, the usual 1px border around grub has been replaced by a series of symbols ..

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This old thread solved an apparently similar problem with a BIOS setting. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1546640&page=2